# Select the equivalent of the clicked element from another group of elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

What I'm tryin is this; when a one of the DIV's from group a is clicked, let the equivalent from group B show. I know it can be done individually like shown in my emaple. Because  the DIV's are generated dynamically and the editor has the right to add hundreds of  DIV's to each group, that wouldn't work. Please what's the best solution for this.

**My Example**

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
         $u=jQuery.noConflict();
           $u("grop a div:nth-of-type(1) ").click(function(){
          $u("group b div:nth-of-type(1) ").show();
        });
           });
```

**DIV group A**

```
    <div></div>
       <div></div>
       <div></div>
    <div></div>
```

**DIV group B**

```
    <div></div>
       <div></div>
       <div></div>
    <div></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
$('#groupA div').click(function () {
    $('#groupB div').eq($(this).index()).show()
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/9ns2j/)**

This uses jQuery's [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) function to get the relative position, index, of the div and apply it to the next group via [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).

Answer (score 2):

First, since the DIVs are added dynamically, you have to use event delegation with `on`. Second, you need to get the clicked element's position in its group, so you can then show the corresponding element in the other group.

```
$u("#groupa").on("click", "> div", function() {
    $u("#groupb > div").eq($(this).index()).show());
});
```

I use the `> div` selector to ensure it only counts direct children, not any DIVs further down the DOM hierarchy.